# error encountered: An unexpected error occured

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made some simple code tests to figure out how this Google-Apps-Script works.

Now I'm facing an error message and I have no idea for what reason. Everything works like I want but running the code ends with a erros message 'error encountered: An unexpected error occured'

I run this code as an Apps-script-gadget on my web-page.

Please help a beginner! :-)

Here the code:

function doGet(e)
{

```
var app1 = UiApp.createApplication();  
app1.add(app1.loadComponent("Panel1")); //Panel1 made with UI-tool
var but1 = app1.getElementById("Button1");
var handler = app1.createServerClickHandler('func1');
but1.addClickHandler(handler);

return app1;
```

}

function func1(e)
{

```
var app2 = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

app2.getElementById("TextBox1").setText("BigBrother");

return app2;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally happening when using `getElementById()` for an element that has no ID... please check in the GUI builder if your TextBox1 does have an ID set with the right value.

EDIT : here is a screen cap.
[image]

and embedded in site :

[image]

[image]

Comment: The ID of the textbox in the GUI-builder is TextBox1. And the text is changing in BigBrother when I press the button. I'm not quiet sure what you mean...

Comment: Is this code you show the complete code you use for testing ? I meant this error is usually showing up when the script doesn't find an element you refer to with its ID. Have you try to use the debug mode ?

Comment: Thats the complete code. The script finds the element because it changes the text like I want after pressing button. In debug mode the code is running without errors.

Comment: I just reproduced your script and got no error... did you save your GUI with the name 'Panel1' ? as this is the 'component name'

Comment: Are you running it as a Apps-script-gadget on your web-page? Does the text change after pressing button? What Internet-browser are you using? I'd like to thank you for your time! :-) And yes, Its saved as Panel1.

Comment: no,yes, chrome, you're welcome (in the right order ;-) I tested as a standalone app, I'll give it a try on a site...

Comment: tested on site, works fine. What Browser do you use ? even if I'm pretty sure this is not related to Browser, the error message comes from GAS. I'm afraid something must be wrong in your GUI ...

Comment: The UI is so simple... maybe you see some problem there, see image.

Comment: I used text area like you and Tadaa! No error. Maybe the text box is "broken"?

Comment: I changed it back to textbox and now it works... strange...  But the case is closed! Thank you very much! :-)